# Clearing or Deleting a Ruby PStore

Tags: ruby, flat-file

I've been experimenting with PStore to hold relatively large numbers of hash values using:

```
 require "pstore"
 store = PStore.new("data.pstore")
```

Seeing as this is stored in a file full of now-useless data, how do I clear or delete the "store" programatically? Obviously I could just delete the `store.pstore` file, but what i'm looking for is the PStore equivalent of:

```
DELETE FROM store WHERE 1=1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/pstore/rdoc/PStore.html#method-i-delete):

```
store.transaction { store.delete(key) }


store = PStore.new("data.pstore")
#=> #<PStore:0x007fd67f35a040 @abort=false, @filename="data.pstore", @lock=#<Thread::Mutex:0x007fd67f359f28>, @thread_safe=false, @ultra_safe=false>
store.transaction { store[:foo] = :bar }
# => #<PStore:0x007fd67f35a040 @abort=false, @filename="data.pstore", @lock=#<Thread::Mutex:0x007fd67f359f28>, @rdonly=false, @table={:foo=>:bar}, @thread_safe=false, @ultra_safe=false>
store.transaction { store.delete(:foo) }
#=> :bar
store
#=> #<PStore:0x007fd67f35a040 @abort=false, @filename="data.pstore", @lock=#<Thread::Mutex:0x007fd67f359f28>, @thread_safe=false, @ultra_safe=false
```

If you want to truncate the `store` you can iterate over the `roots` and delete them in a transaction:

```
store.transaction do
  store.roots.each do |root|
    store.delete(root)
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think ObjectSpace mumbo-jumbo is relevant here. Do you think he has hundreds-thousands of PStore objects randomly lying around?

Comment: Also, the question was: how to truncate the store?

Comment: Also, no need for shelling out when there is ruby api for deleting files :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev to truncate the store (if I understand it correctly) one just would iterate over table's keys (`store.roots`) and delete them, unless there is more efficient one-go method for it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev about ObjectSpace - you must be right, just didn't think of a better way to get all `PStore` objects. What do you mean by "shelling out"? If you mean `rm` thing - it's just that I wasn't able to delete the file with `File.delete` - or did I just have something messed up? I always appreciate your input, so thx in advance!

Comment: Yes, "to shell out" means going to the OS/shell to do some stuff. In this case, deleting a file by executing `rm` command in a subprocess. It's interesting, why couldn't you delete it with `File.delete`? Perhaps the file was still open by the store?

Comment: "a better way to get all PStore objects" - there is only one object in the question. :)

Comment: Yes, I think the way to go is iterate roots and delete them in a transaction. Could you put that into the answer (and remove the objectspace part)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev edited.  just tried it now and `File.delete(File.absolute_path(store.path))` and got `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /path/to/data.pstore`.. (`"data.pstore"` is a filename)

Comment: When I do `File.delete(store.path)` it returns `1`, but I still can access `store` object..

Comment: @SergioTulentsev edited the answer, don't know why yesterday I wrote it the way I did..?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant 